# Взаимодействие if и for

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. Проблема состоит в том, что программа должна получить 0.099 из 99.На выходе 99. Что неправильно?

```
    int ig = 4;
    int it = 1;
    int peremenaja = it - ig;
    float cislo = 99;
    float ir;
    if (peremenaja<0){
        float irr = cislo;
        int ip = peremenaja;
        for (int o = ip;o==0;o++){
            irr = irr/10;
            if (ig == 5){
                irr = irr / 100;
            }
        }
        ir = irr;
    }
    else {
        float irr = cislo;
        int ip = peremenaja;
        for (int o = ip;o==0;o--){
            irr = irr*10;
            if (it == 5){
                irr = irr * 100;
            }
        }
        ir = irr;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте заменить

```
for (int o = ip;o==0;o++){
```

на

```
for (int o = ip;o <= 0;o++){
```

[ваш код](https://ideone.com/Iko11w)

Answer (score 1):

Как-то много кода у вас для такой простенькой задачи...

```
int number = 99, i = 10; 
float result;
while(true){
    if (number/i==0) break;
    else i*=10;
}
result= (float)number/i/10;
```